# JSP request getting closed without any response for the last request when url is accessed by multiple users. What could be the reason?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am developing a web app which will take a file through POST request from JSP and perform some processing on file and send response as excel sheet being downloaded. Sometimes all requests work perfectly but sometimes 4th or last request gets stopped on browser but in back end file is generated without any exception.

Comment: Maybe a timeout?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what does not work, **show your code** instead. Without code, we can only guess.